# Can I use {self.attribute} directly after a module name in Python?

Tags: python, list, oop

I have a database:

```
films = [
    ("Blade Runner (1982)", "vhf"),
    ("Alien : Le 8ème Passager (1979)", "vhf"),
    ("2001 : L'Odyssée de l'espace (1968)", "VhF"),
    ("Matrix (1999)", "DVD"),
    ("Interstellar (2014)", "dvD"),
    ("L'Empire contre-attaque (1980)", "vhf"),
    ("Retour vers le futur (1985)", "vhf"),
    ("La Guerre des Étoiles (1977)", "vhf"),
    ("L'Armée des 12 singes (1995)", "dVd"),
    ("Terminator 2 : Le Jugement dernier (1991)", "DVD"),
]
friends = [
    ("Paul", "Blade Runner"),
    ("Lucie",),
    ("Zoé", "Terminator 2 : Le Jugement dernier"),
]
```

I want to do a cleaning tool that lowercase and delete the films' date in the list, but I want that tool to be usable even if we add lists in the database.

So I did that, but it doesn't work:

```
import re
import database as db


class CleaningTool:
    def __init__(self, listname):
        self.listname = listname
    def clean(self):
        list = db.{self.listname}
        list_strings = [', '.join(i) for i in list]
        list_strings_lowercase = [x.lower() for x in list_strings]
        list_strings_lowercase_nodate = [re.sub(r' \([^)]*\)', '', film) for film in list_strings_lowercase]
        return list_strings_lowercase_nodate


cleaningtool = CleaningTool("films")
cleaningtool.clean()
```

I wanted to be able to inject the argument of the cleaning tool into the function "clean". If I could do that, I would be able to choose which list I want to clean in the database, enabling me to use it later in the code.

Comment: Why not just pass the list in directly? `cleaningtool = CleaningTool(db.films)`? (and `list_strings = [', '.join(i) for i in self.listname]`)

Comment: That's it. I'm so dumb haha. Than you very much!